# API doesn't return 404 correctly

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

I have developed backend application in sailsjs. I have a route defined in my route.js as below

```
[`PUT ${prefix}/orgs/:orgId/samples/:sampleId`]
```

from postman I am calling API url like
`http://.../orgs/123/samples/testall`

Here there is no routes as `/samples/testall` but still it matches to  `/samples/:sampleId` and 'testall' is considered as value for 'sampleId'.

how can I avoid this and return 404 error for `http://.../orgs/123/samples/testall` this API call?

Comment: Can you explicitly have :sampleId typed as an integer? Currently, it seems the REST interface is willing to view it as a String

Comment: @morsor we have sampleId as '2c9180827d9ccb93017dbccee4834000' , so not typed as integer.

Comment: If you cannot type :sampleId as an Integer or something more specific than merely a String, perhaps running a validation which upon failure returns a 404 response is an option?